# Allow users to save queries/search parameters in Alfresco Share

Tags: alfresco, alfresco-share

Our Share users currently have a static large list of parameters that they need to manually re-input everytime documents needs to be searched.

Is there any way of saving search/queries in Alfresco share?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This function was available in the g'old explorer UI, but unfortunately never got into Alfrescp Share or into Alfresco Digital Workspace. As a work around you may take a look into the [Saved Search dashlet](https://docs.alfresco.com/6.1/tasks/customize-savedsearch.html) ?

Comment: Thanks! That works. It's a bit of a workaround tho, but that is enough for us.

Comment: Kudos for remembering Explorer, times when you could have actually executed a rule in a matter of seconds.

Comment: I also wonder that hip frameworks may replace functionality/usability ...

Answer (score 0):

There is a dashlet called Saved Search available.You can use that or you can create similar dashlet with your customization.